# Record video with screen off

Tags: video

I want to record a long video with my phone but I will not be near a power source. Is there a way to turn off the screen while recording to save battery life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app that I've used that lets you record video with the screen off. It has tons of other goodies too, but this isn't the place for it. "Security Toolkit" has a motion sensor activated security recording feature. After some tweaking you probably can get it to do what you want it to.

[This link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/publishers/Venetasoft%E2%84%A2?appid=773e113b-47e0-4a34-9824-e94b8f3871d2&name=Venetasoft%E2%84%A2) will bring you to their app list. You can choose the entire toolkit or just get the motion camera portion (my favorite part).

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work. Can you double check it?

Comment: It works for me, here is the long version: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/publishers/Venetasoft%E2%84%A2?appid=773e113b-47e0-4a34-9824-e94b8f3871d2&name=Venetasoft%E2%84%A2

Comment: odd...it works from my desktop, but not my phone.  Oh well Great tip!

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this natively. However, I don't think there is any reason why an app couldn't be created to do so. It would be a bit tricky, but could be done.

That being said, I look through the marketplace and didn't see anything that **would** do that. If you have some developer friends, perhaps that can put something together for you.

Comment: I thought that when the screen is off the application gets tombstoned and can only do a limited amount of things as a background task?

Comment: Well, the application can request to disable lock, and you could intercept the inbound camera data, choose NOT to display it on the screen (showing a solid black color instead) and instead capture the video directly and save it to disk. Like I said, it would be some work to do it :)

Comment: @row1 You can certainly write an app that runs under the lock screen, for example exercise apps that track your movements keep alive and use the aGPS systems to do so. I guess you could continue using the the camera...