# Can I lock my phone while filming?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, camera

Last week I bought a waterproof case for my Nokia Lumia 920.

When I want to film something underwater, one of the bottom buttons is being pressed, so the app stops and my phone also stops recording.

Is there an app or a setting to say that when my phone is filming, the only way to stop is to press the physical camera button?

Comment: Sounds like a faulty case, if it's causing a button to be pressed when it isn't...

Comment: Try lowering the touch sensitivity on your phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record video with screen off](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/849/record-video-with-screen-off)